# How to unpack a C struct of unknown, varible length from a UDP datagram in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to ingest some binary UDP data in python.   The source data (ADCP water column data in the Kongsberg CP1 data format) comes in as a single UDP datagram that looks like this:

--- START DATAGRAM

```
struct CurrentProfileStruct
{
public short MessageId;
public short MessageVersion;
public ulong PingTime;
public float StartRange;
public float SampleInterval;
public short NumberOfValues;
public bool IsVesselRelative;
public bool IsValidBottomData;
public float BottomVelocityNorth;
public float BottomVelocityEast;
public float VesselHeading;
}
```

Start loop (NumberOfValues):

```
struct CurrentSampleStruct
{
public float VelocityNorth;
public float VelocityEast;
public bool ValidData;
}
```

end loop

```
public short Terminator;
```

--- END OF DATAGRAM

The trick is that the count of the collection of CurrentSampleStruct sub-structs in the 'NumberOfValues' loop is unknown until you can read the first struct in the datagram and extract the NumberOfValues parameter.

I have the UDP reader working, and I can read the raw binary datagrams just fine, but I am stumped as to how to unpack a struct without knowning it's full content ahead of time.

```
import socket
import datetime
import struct

## Configs
UDP_IP = "<IP OF SOURCE>"
UDP_PORT = <UDP PORT> #datagram port

## Creating socket object
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  #AF_INET specifies that IPs are going to be used. #DGRAM specifies that it is going to be under UDP
address = (UDP_IP,      # IP Address
           UDP_PORT)    # UDP Port
sock.bind(address)

## startup message
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().time()
print("Staring up at :",timestamp)
print("-------------------------------------------")

## quick loop to 5 packets during testing
i = 1
while i < 5:
    # Function to receive data
    data,senderaddr = sock.recvfrom(10240000) # Argument is the buffer size (maximum size of data being received at once). # Two outputs are given, the "data" output and the "address from senders" output.
    print("Incoming Datagram:",data)
    thisStruct = struct.unpack('hhLffh??fffff?h', data)
    print(thisStruct)
    i = i + 1
```

This produces:

```
Staring up at : 11:43:55.354576
-------------------------------------------
Incoming Datagram: b'\xb1\x00\x00\x00\xf8$\x92`\xe3o\xd9\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0@\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xae\x87OC\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
    thisStruct = struct.unpack('hhLffh??fffff?h', data)
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 52 bytes
```

Comment: Since `CurrentProfileStruct` is a fixed size, you can read the first 52 bytes of the packet and interpret that as the `CurrentProfileStruct`. If you don't know how big the struct is, you can check with [struct.calcsize()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.calcsize).

Comment: You can slice a bytes object to extract the first 52 bytes using `data[:52]`.

Comment: As an aside, isn't the largest datagram packet 65,527 bytes? (that's IP6, a bit shorter for IP4). 10240000 is overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might try something like this, putting all the sample structs in a list:

```
...
# Function to receive data
data,senderaddr = sock.recvfrom(10240000) # Argument is the buffer size (maximum size of data being received at once). # Two outputs are given, the "data" output and the "address from senders" output.
print("Incoming Datagram:",data)
profileStructSize = struct.calcsize('hhLffh??fff')
thisStruct = struct.unpack('hhLffh??fff', data[:profileStructSize])
print(thisStruct)

# unpack sample structs
# NumberOfValues is at index 5 in the tuple
listOfSampleStructs = []
dataIndex = profileStructSize
sampleStructSize = struct.calcsize('ff?')
for j in range(thisStruct[5]):
  listOfSampleStructs.append(struct.unpack('ff?', data[dataIndex:dataIndex + sampleStructSize])
  dataIndex += sampleStructSize
```